# all the href link in my html page go to the same folder if I add javascript in the html project

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, href, location-href

This is my folder:

[image: that's my folder]

The problem is the javascript file, all the href in all html file is correct but if I add script.js at the pages when I click on the subs menu of the javascript's dropdown menu all the link go to the last folder, in this case curiosità.

if I delete the div (drop-down-menu-content) of curiosità all the link go to opere and so on.
I tried everything in the html file and also in javascript file but after a lot of ours I'm at the same point

```js
var menuItems = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.menu__item')),
  menuSubs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-menu')),
  selectedMenu = undefined,
  subBg = document.querySelector('.dropdown__bg'),
  subBgBtm = document.querySelector('.dropdown__bg-bottom'),
  subArr = document.querySelector('.dropdown__arrow'),
  subCnt = document.querySelector('.dropdown__wrap'),
  header = document.querySelector('.main-header'),
  closeDropdownTimeout,

  startCloseTimeout = function() {
    closeDropdownTimeout = setTimeout(() => closeDropdown(), 50);
    console.log(header);
  },

  stopCloseTimeout = function() {
    clearTimeout(closeDropdownTimeout);
  },

  openDropdown = function(el) {
    //- get menu ID
    var menuId = el.getAttribute('data-sub');
    //- get related sub menu
    var menuSub = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu[data-sub="' + menuId + '"]');
    //- get menu sub content
    var menuSubCnt = menuSub.querySelector('.dropdown-menu__content');
    //- get bottom section of current sub
    var menuSubBtm = menuSubCnt.querySelector('.bottom-section').getBoundingClientRect();
    //- get height of top section
    var menuSubTop = menuSubCnt.querySelector('.top-section').getBoundingClientRect();

    //- get menu position
    var menuMeta = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    //- get sub menu position
    var subMeta = menuSubCnt.getBoundingClientRect();

    //- set selected menu
    selectedMenu = menuId;

    //- Remove active Menu
    menuItems.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    //- Set current menu to active
    el.classList.add('active');

    //- Remove active sub menu
    menuSubs.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));
    //- Set current menu to active
    menuSub.classList.add('active');

    //- Set dropdown menu background style to match current submenu style
    subBg.style.opacity = 1;
    subBg.style.left = menuMeta.left - (subMeta.width / 2 - menuMeta.width / 2) + 'px';
    subBg.style.width = subMeta.width + 'px';
    subBg.style.height = subMeta.height + 'px';
    //- Set dropdown menu bottom section background position
    subBgBtm.style.top = menuSubTop.height + 'px';

    //- Set Arrow position
    subArr.style.opacity = 1;
    subArr.style.left = menuMeta.left + menuMeta.width / 2 - 10 + 'px';

    //- Set sub menu style
    subCnt.style.opacity = 1;
    subCnt.style.left = menuMeta.left - (subMeta.width / 2 - menuMeta.width / 2) + 'px';
    subCnt.style.width = subMeta.width + 'px';
    subCnt.style.height = subMeta.height + 'px';

    //- Set current sub menu style
    menuSub.style.opacity = 1;

    header.classList.add('dropdown-active');
  },

  closeDropdown = function() {
    //- Remove active class from all menu items
    menuItems.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('active'));

    //- Remove active class from all sub menus
    menuSubs.forEach(el => {
      el.classList.remove('active');
      el.style.opacity = 0;
    });
    //- set sub menu background opacity
    subBg.style.opacity = 0;
    //- set arrow opacity
    subArr.style.opacity = 0;

    // unset selected menu
    selectedMenu = undefined;

    header.classList.remove('dropdown-active');
  };

//- Binding mouse event to each menu items
menuItems.forEach(el => {
  //- mouse enter event
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {

    stopCloseTimeout();
    openDropdown(this);
  }, false);

  //- mouse leave event
  el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => startCloseTimeout(), false);
});

//- Binding mouse event to each sub menus
menuSubs.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => stopCloseTimeout(), false);
  el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => startCloseTimeout(), false);
});
```

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla';
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, #25ddf5, #53f);
  font-family: karla;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 18px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #444;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve3d;
  perspective: 3000px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu a {
  padding: 20px 20px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.menu__item {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.menu__item:hover>.sub-menu-shadow {
  display: block;
}

.menu .sub-menu-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown-holder {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown__bg,
.dropdown__arrow {
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown__arrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent white;
  top: -20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown__bg {
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown__bg-bottom {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 300px;
  height: 700px;
  transition: 0.3s ease;
}

.dropdown__wrap {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown__wrap .top-section,
.dropdown__wrap .bottom-section {
  padding: 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu__content {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
  min-width: 50px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-menu__content ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu__content a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.dropdown-menu__content h3 {
  color: blue;
}

.dropdown-menu__content a:hover {
  color: #333;
}

.dropdown-menu.active .dropdown-menu__content {
  opacity: 1;
}

#opere .dropdown-menu__content,
#vita .dropdown-menu__content,
#curiositÃ .dropdown-menu__content {
  width: 640px;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
}

.col>ul,
.col>div {
  flex: 1 0 150px;
}

.menu-title {
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #2196F3;
}


/* TITOLO*/

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Righteous');
@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    left: 100%
  }
  100% {
    left: 50%
  }
}

@keyframes fadeInBottom {
  0% {
    top: 100%
  }
  100% {
    top: 50%
  }
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 5em;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 94vh;
  color: #fafafa;
  animation-delay: 3s;
  animation: colorFlip 3.5s infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
  bottom: 60px;
}

.from-right,
.from-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10em;
  height: 2em;
  margin-left: -5em;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.from-right {
  margin-top: -1em;
  animation: fadeInRight 2s 1;
}

.from-bottom {
  animation: fadeInBottom 2s 1;
}

.jamesjoyce {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.fotojoyce {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 0;
}

.container2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.curiosita {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  height: 60%;
  width: 80%;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>James Joyce</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/gsap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.11.5/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
</head>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<header class="main-header">
  <ul class="menu">
    <div class="jamesjoyce">
      <li><a href="./index.html">James Joyce</a></li>
    </div>

    <li class="menu__item" data-sub="vita"><a>Vita</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item" data-sub="opere"><a>Opere</a></li>
    <li class="menu__item" data-sub="curiosità"><a>Curiosità</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="dropdown-holder">
    <div class="dropdown__arrow"></div>
    <div class="dropdown__bg">
      <div class="dropdown__bg-bottom"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown__wrap">

      <!-- VITA-->
      <div class="dropdown-menu" id="vita" data-sub="vita">
        <div class="dropdown-menu__content" id="vita" data-sub="vita">
          <div class="top-section">
            <div class="col">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="./vita/trieste.html">
                    <h3>Trieste</h3>
                    <p> Trieste was an important meeting point for several writers, including: Italo Svevo and James Joyce</p>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="./vita/svevo.html">
                    <h3>Svevo</h3>
                    <p>The friendship between Svevo and Joyce began when Svevo decided to follow the lessons of the then beginner teacher, Joyce. From there was born a wonderful friendship that lasted for years</p>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="./vita/studi.html">
                    <h3>Education</h3>
                    <p>Joyce signed up at University College Dublin in 1898, where he studied modern languages. Later he taught at the Berlitz School in Trieste</p>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom-section">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <!-- OPERE-->
      <div class="dropdown-menu" id="opere" data-sub="opere">
        <div class="dropdown-menu__content" id="opere" data-sub="opere">
          <div class="top-section">
            <div class="col">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="./opere/theDubliners.html">
                    <h3>The Dubliners</h3>
                    <p> Dubliners is a collection of 15 short stories set in Dublin, published in 1914. Represent an ideal portrait of the irish capital in the 20 th century</p>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="./opere/ulysses.html">
                    <h3>Ulysses</h3>
                    <p>Ulysses is a long complex novel set in Dublin on one single day and the 18 episodes correspond to Homer's Odyssey</p>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="./opere/finnegansWake.html">
                    <h3>Finnegans Wake</h3>
                    <p> Finnegans Wake is a novel by James Joyce that is known for its difficult and obscure language. The book tells the story of a man named Humphrey and his family</p>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom-section">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



      <!-- CURIOSITA'-->
      <div class="dropdown-menu" id="curiosità" data-sub="curiosità">
        <div class="dropdown-menu__content" id="curiosità" data-sub="curiosità">
          <div class="top-section">
            <div class="col">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="./curiosità/1.html">
                    <h3>Ernest Hemingway was his drinking buddy in Paris.</h3>
                    <p>Having met at Shakespeare and Company, Joyce and Hemingway had quickly become drinking buddies.</p>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="./curiosità/2.html">
                    <h3>He invented a 100-letter word to describe thunder</h3>
                    <p>Joyce invented a word to describe thunder in Finnegans Wake.</p>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="./curiosità/3.html">
                    <h3>Joyce had bad eyesight</h3>
                    <p> Joyce had bad eyesight and was almost blind by the time he died. He had 25 operations on his eyes.</p>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="bottom-section">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<body>

  <!--TITOLO-->
  <div class="title">
    <div class="from-right">James</div>
    <div class="from-bottom">Joyce</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container2">
    <img class="fotojoyce" id="joyce" src="img/joyce.png" alt="">
  </div>





  <!-- partial -->
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
  <script src="./fotojoyce.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There's no need to use `[].slice.call()` these days. Use `[...document.querySelectorAll('.menu__item')]` to convert to an array.

Comment: I don't see anything here that changes where a link goes to.

Comment: I can't figure out how to click on the links that pop up when I hover over a title, because they go away when I try to move the mouse to them. Is there missing CSS in the snippet?

Comment: yes i miss to send the .css file

Comment: without slice.call I have the same problem

Comment: Slice.call has nothing to do with the problem, it's just general coding advice.

Comment: Can you update the snippet so we can run it and see the problem?

Comment: yes I can, I'm adding .css file now

Comment: The problem is that setting opacity: 0 to hide the non-active content doesn't prevent clicking on it. So all the anchors are there, and when you click it clicks on the last one, even if it's not visible. You can use z-axis to move the active one to the top of the stack.